# expand/collapse jquery menu (can't find right selector)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using an unordered list for my menu .. I've got the selection for the click working, but I can't figure out the selection for only the specific list. The way I have it now, it expands/collapses all the lists with the specific class, but I only want to have it on the class I've clicked in..

**Here is the jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".login-holder > ul > #loginTitle").click(function() {
            $(".account-links:parent").slideToggle("medium");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div class="login-holder">

      <p><strong>Welcome, <%= ViewModel.Profile.Name.First %></strong></p>

      <ul class="account-links">
         <span id="loginTitle">User Options</span><br /><br />
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<EventController>( x => x.List(), "Events Near Me" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<MyEventsController>( x => x.List(), "My Events" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.Edit(), "My Profile" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<ClubController>( x => x.List(), "Clubs Near Me" )%>
         </li>
         <li> 
            <%= Html.ActionLink<MyClubsController>( x => x.List(), "My Clubs" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.ChangePassword(), "Change My Password" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<DependantController>( x => x.List(), "My Dependants" ) %>
         </li>

      </ul>
   </div>
  <div class="login-holder">
     <ul class="account-links">
        <span id="loginTitle">Organizer Details<!--<span id="toggle" style="margin-left: 32px; padding-right: 10px;"></span>--></span><br /><br />
        <!--<div id="additions">-->
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.Organizer(), "Organizer Details" )%>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<EventController>( x => x.Edit( default(int?) ), "Post An Event" )%>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<EventAdminController>( x => x.List(), "Events Created By Me" ) %>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<ClubController>( x => x.Edit( default( int? ) ), "Create A Club" )%>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<ClubAdminController>( x => x.List( ), "Clubs Created By Me" )%>
        </li>
        <!--</div>-->
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are a few things wrong here, repeated IDs and a `<span>` can't be a direct child of a `<ul>`...also what is initially hidden?

Comment: nothing is initially hidden .. yea the repeated IDs I know is wrong, they should be classes as I am using that to style the list headers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the non-standards compliant HTML, this should give you the functionality you want

```
$("#loginTitle").click(function() {
    $(".login-holder").find("li").slideToggle("medium");
});
```

You should not use the same ID "loginTitle" for more than 1 element, try switching it to a css class and change the selector above to `.loginTitle`

Comment: Thanks for that - that will still collapse all of the list items underneath .. I only want one section at a time to be collapsed ..

Comment: ahh .. that works perfect now, I'll fix the ID's to be classes as well for compliancy

Comment: please note that it's not going to work unless you change that ID to a class, you shouldn't have the same ID more than once on a page.